# have to create a matlab counter

Tags: matlab, counter

Q- Create a "counter" from 0:limit-1 (for example if you choose 3 it will display 0,1,2). The length of counter is not determined in the program and it should be determined when it is being run and the inputs can differ from each other

Comment: Is this a homework problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: this is the function for input vector of  size 3 you, can try running it. now we have to make a counter which will run for an input vector of any size so how will it be done? this is my question:function neha(limit)
    c = zeros(1,3);
    for i = 0:limit(3)-1 % same as running it from 1:limit(3)
        c(3)=i;
        for j = 0:limit(2)-1
            c(2)=j;
            for k=0:limit(1)-1
                c(1)=k;
                for x=3:-1:1
                    fprintf('%d ',c(x))
                end
                fprintf('\n');
            end
        end
    end
return

Answer (score 1):

not really sure what you mean...but

```
for i = 0:limit-1
    disp(i)
end
```

will display 0,1,2 ... limit-1